# The session works on the local server, but not on the web server

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with a session, it works fine on the local server, but it's not visible on the server, the project is in wordpress, do I have to set something special about wordpress? This is my code .. Thank you very much for the answer.

```
session_start();
```

I made a session on this ID (that's my ID that I'm sending to the server) he's in the session

```
    $user_id = $arr['id'];
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;    
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
if($user_id){
     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
```

In this file, I need to get that ID from the session, but the server does not see it.
but on the local server everything works

```
    public static function save_account_details() {

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    //var_dump($user_id);
    //die();

    if ( 'POST' !== strtoupper( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( empty( $_POST['action'] ) || 'save_account_details' !== $_POST['action'] || empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'save_account_details' ) ) {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this in a plugin or on a template file?

Also, you certainly want to ensure that you're properly setting up sessions. I recommend doing so in functions.php. e.g:

```
add_action('init', 'track_sessions', 1);
 function track_sessions() { // if session isn't active, set it
  if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
   }
}
```

And using them as you are:

```
$_SESSION['my_val'] = $val;
```

Once done, you need to destroy the session:

```
add_action( 'your_action_here', 'destroy_session', 10, 5 );

 // All done. Destroy session

function destroy_session() {
   session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is all in my plugins, can I just put something in the configuration file for the session?

Comment: What do you mean it is all in your 'plugins'? WP has its own sessions, from your code above, it is not clear whether you're checking for active sessions before `session_start()`, or whether you're starting the session multiple times in your plugin(s). To troubleshoot, I'd move the above to functions.php .